# SqlConnection to localdb fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my controller I'm trying to access the `MembershipUser`:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I was able to create the user and I'm able to see the entry in the

```
[projInterview].[dbo].[AspNetUsers]
```

I've been able to seed my other tables. **But I can't seem to access the `MembershipUser` in my controller in the `Create` method.**

I'm not sure where to look. I've checked the web.config and I'm not sure what the issue is:

**Update:**

I added the following to my web.config:

```
<membership 
    defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
    userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
    <providers>
       <remove name="AspNetSqlProvider" />
       <add name="SqlProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="ProjectContext"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
            passwordFormat="Hashed"
            applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Now I'm getting the error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Full `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ProjectContext" 
           connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Initial Catalog=projInterview;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\projInterview.mdf" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <membership 
             defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
             userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
             <providers>
                <remove name="AspNetSqlProvider" />
                <add name="SqlProvider"
                    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                    connectionStringName="ProjectContext"
                    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                    enablePasswordReset="true"
                    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
                    passwordFormat="Hashed"
                    applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>  
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>  
  </entityFramework>
  <!--<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="projInterview.DAL.ProjectContext, projInterview">
        <databaseInitializer type="projInterview.DAL.ProjectContext, projInterview" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>-->
  <!--<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>-->
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to have any configuration for the membership system. By default, it will use the `LocalSqlServer` connection string defined in the machine-level config file, which almost certainly isn't what you want:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add 
        name="LocalSqlServer" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" 
    />
</connectionStrings>
```

You need to create [the `system.web/membership` configuration element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1b9hw62f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to configure the membership provider to use your database.

---

**Update:**
Your database needs to contain the relevant tables and stored procedures for the `SqlMembershipProvider` to work. The easiest way to create them is with [the aspnet_regsql utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you could use [the Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx), which use Entity Framework Code First, and will automatically create the required tables for you.

Finally, you might want to consider ditching the Membership system and using [the new ASP.NET Identity system](http://www.asp.net/identity) instead.

Comment: I updated my question.  I'm getting a new error: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Comment: I tried the first two options and it got me passed my 1st issue but now I'm wondering about the new ASP.Net Identity system.